# Random size divs

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder if anyone could help me. I'm trying to find a script that will fill a 1000x1000 box with randomly generated divs (few variations of size and absolutely random position). Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean filling it completely, as in a random partition, or just filling it with a few, that may overlap?

Comment: I mean completely filling it without any gaps

Comment: What would the divs contain? Can they overlap each other? We need more details before being able to help.

Comment: The divs will contain a media content, implemented by php. No, they can't overlap each other. Appreciate the help, guys!

Comment: task sounds a little bit crazy :) is it homework or your client is mad? :)

Comment: I found this awesome resource http://thejit.org/demos/ it realy helped me :)

Comment: @vhl so you got what you wanted or are you still looking for help?

Comment: I found this http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example2.html It's awesome but not random and a little bit complicated for me. So i am still searching...

Comment: @vhl and Marnix answer? Not your cup of tea?

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach could be to create a treemap. The treemap is a special way of visualizing a tree.

What is strange about a treemap, is that it is specified by its leafs only. The parents are most of the time just thrown away, because they are irrelevant to the treemap. The size of each div is implemented by the value of the node. The size of the parent is then just a sum of all children.

I think you should read more about [treemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), because they are actually quite easy. I found this [javascript](http://js-treemap.sourceforge.net/) as well. Maybe you could look at the code and change it a bit, so it won't reveal the parents anymore and just create a treemap of leafs.

And I found this link for a nice [JS-visualization lib](http://www.jsviz.org/blog/).

[image: treemap of a hard disk]